# Magento custom payment method title not shown in checkout

Tags: magento, module, payment-gateway

I am covering [this](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method) tutorial and I have a first little problem. While the new method appears in admin list and in checkout page, it doesn't get the default title.

I also took a look at the core config files for the "built in" payment methods and I can not see the difference.

Got any ideea what could it be?

(I am running Magento 1.7)

This is how I try to indicate to magento the default title for checkout

```
<default>
        <payment>
            <globalpay>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>globalpay/pay</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <title>Pay Method</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
            </globalpay>
         </payment>
    </default>
```

and this is how I declare the field in admin section of Magento

```
 <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <comment>Insert a custom title for this payment method</comment>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <order_status translate="label">
                            <label>New order status</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>                   <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_processing</source_model>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </order_status>
```

I also tried to remove the field (the second snippet), thinking that while I don't know how to set a default value for it (by the way, how could I do that? - Probably it shold be stored in db on setup, or could it be served by a model through source_model tag ??) but it did'nt work.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the payment title show up in Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Payment Methods -> globalpay (tab)?

Comment: R.S, sorry for the delay (GTM fault:) ). Yes, I get the title field in that tab. It is empty. If I fill it it appears in frontend/checkout. But I'm considering the fact that this module/extension will be added to several customers and it would be great if there would be a default title. THank you!

Comment: So the issue you are having is 'Setting Default Title not working'... Does the other defaults e.g. 'active' or 'order_status' work? What is the file location of your '<default>' xml code, is it app/local/CompanyName/globalpay/etc/config.xml

Comment: I use 2 xml files which are placed in etc folder: config.xml and system.xml. The other fields behave as expected - they retreive there data from the sugested model and append it to the select node.

Comment: Could you update the code above and add 'active' or 'order_status'

Comment: Try change this <show_in_store>1</show_in_store> to <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>

Comment: It was 0. I changed it in the same ideea..